# What is the RE to match the list?

Tags: python, regex

I want to know how to construct the regular express to extract the list.

Here is my string:

```
audit = "{## audit_filter = ['hostname.*','service.*'] ##}"
```

Here is my expression:

```
AUDIT_FILTER_RE = r'([.*])'
```

And here is my search statement:

```
audit_filter = re.search(AUDIT_FILTER_RE, audit).group(1)
```

I want to extract everything inside the square brackets including the brackets. '[...]'

Expected Output:

```
['hostname.*','service.*']
```

Comment: `print(re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", audit))`

Comment: I might recommend `(\[[^\]]+\])`, in case of multiple lists (though not nested lists.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
audit = "{## audit_filter = ['hostname.*','service.*'] ##}"
print eval(re.findall(r"\[.*\]", audit)[0]) # ['hostname.*', 'service.*']
```

`findall` returns a list of string matches. In your case, there should only be one, so I'm retrieving the string at index 0, which is a *string representation of a list*. Then, I use `eval(...)` to convert that string representation of a list to an actual list. Just beware:

- If there are no matches, ...findall...[0] will throw a list index out of range error
- Don't use `eval()` if you ever expect input coming from another source (i.e. input that is not yours) because that would be a security issue.

Comment: Thank you Sir! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Use `r"\[(.*?)\]"`

**Ex:**

```
import re
audit = "{## audit_filter = ['hostname.*'] ##}"
print(re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", audit))
```

**Output:**

```
["'hostname.*'"]
```

Comment: The RE picks up the double quotes? I just want the single quotes and no double quotes...